# How can I redirect to login_path if email uniqueness validation fails?

Tags: forms, validation, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am creating my very first Rails and MVC app. It is a website for my wedding guests to create their RSVPs.

I have a single form that is deeply nested. An RSVP has_one User and has_many Guests.

This form creates a User, RSVP, and Guests all in one go. There is also a link to edit an existing RSVP through a login_path.

I have validates_uniqueness_of :email on the User model. I would like to redirect to the login_path if a user attempts to create a new RSVP when they've already created one, i.e. the :email :uniqueness validation fails.

How can I redirect to the login_path if the :email :uniqueness validation fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to test in your controller action  if the unique validation failed for the that email and redirect if that's the case. That said, I'm not sure if there is better way to know if a certain validation failed for an specific field than just comparing the error message, as follows:

```
if @user.save
  # do success actions
else
  if @user.errors[:email] == 'has already been taken' # ugh
    respond_to |format|
      format.html { redirect_to login_path(email: @user.email) }
    end
  else
    # handle other errors
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess it's because the user is created in the RSVP controller, but @rsvp.errors[:email] doesn't work. So, I had to use the even clumsier @rsvp.errors.full_messages.include?. Thanks for your help!